# How to ignore failure of command called through command builtin?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, sh

I have a shell script (running on macOS with GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release) where I `set -e` at the beginning, but I also want to ignore some of the potential failures, so that they don't end the execution of the script. I'm doing that by appending `|| ...` to the relevant commands:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
false || echo ignore failure
```

The above works and outputs `ignore failure`, as expected.

However, if I call the `false` command through the `command` builtin, this strategy doesn't work -- the following version of the script exits as soon as `false` fails, without printing anything:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
command false || echo ignore failure
```

Why is that? How can I get the desired behavior of ignoring the failure even in the second case?

(In this simplified example, I could of course just delete the `command` builtin, but in my actual use case, it's part of a function that I don't control.)

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Which shell do you use? bash, sh or zsh?

Comment: I wonder if it is parsing the `||` as an argument to `false`.   Is `( command false ) || echo ignore failure` any better? What happens if you do `command echo hello || echo goodbye`?

Comment: @Abelisto I know, I'm using `set -e` because I generally want to stop execution on failure (in the original script that the example has been condensed from). But there are a few commands where I don't, which is what I'm using `|| ...` for.

Comment: @Cyrus On macOS, they're both bash (version 3.2.57(1)-release), but I tried running the script with both for good measure, in case bash changes the behavior depending on what program name it's run as. The results are the same in both cases.

Comment: @NateEldredge Interesting ideas! `command echo hello || echo goodbye` prints `hello`, so it looks like `||` is parsed correctly? But more importantly, it looks like `( command false ) || echo ignore failure` works! Not entirely sure why though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why does `command false || echo` fail?

Seems like this is a bug in bash versions below 4.0.

I downloaded the [old versions](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/) 3.2.57 and 4.0, compiled them on Linux, and ran your script. I could reproduce your problem in 3.2.57. In 4.0 everything worked as expected.

Strangely, I couldn't find an according note in bash's lists [list of changes](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES), but if you search for `set -e` you find multiple other bugfixes regarding the behavior of `set -e`in other versions, for instance:

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.4-rc1, and
> the previous version, bash-4.4-beta.
> [...]
> o.  Fixed a bug that caused set -e to be honored in cases of builtins invoking other builtins when it should be ignored.

### How to fix the problem?

The best way would be to use more recent version of bash. Even on macOS this shouldn't be a problem. You can compile it yourself or install it from something like `brew`.

Other than that, you can use workarounds like leaving out `command` or adding a subshell `( command false; ) || echo ignore failure` (courtesy of [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68143965/how-to-ignore-failure-of-command-called-through-command-builtin/68144864?noredirect=1#comment120438591_68143965)). In either case, things get quite cumbersome. As you don't know when exactly the bug happens you cannot be sure that you correctly worked around it every time.

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much for chasing this down! Does the subshell workaround mentioned in one of the comments on OP work for you (`( command false ) || echo ignore failure`)? It did for me. If it does for you too, then maybe it would make sense to add it to the answer, crediting @NateEldredge, who originally came up with it? I'm happy to accept the answer then -- with a likely cause and a workaround, there's probably not much point in investigating further.

Comment: Sorry, the page updated with your edit including workarounds just as I was posting my previous comment :)